# Adding sources to Eclipse CDT project gives error: folder "overlaps the location of the project that contains the linked resource"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am having problems adding another "linked folder" to the list of source file locations in my Eclipse CDT project.

My project is located at 
`/m/a/prj/eclipse` and my sources are at
`/m/a/src`
`/m/b/src`
`/m/c/src`
etc.

However, when I try to add
`/m`
to the list of source folders, I get error:

```
"Cannot create a link to '....../m' because 
it overlaps the location of the project that contains the linked resource."
```

I tried manualy editing `.project` file, but that gave the same error after reloading the project.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Can you create individual source folders for `/m/a/src`, `/m/b/src`, etc.?

Comment: How do you mean? Please more details.

Comment: You were trying to add the `/m` folder itself as a source folder, and the problem is that the project folder (`/m/a/prj/eclipse`) is inside `/m`. If you try adding `/m/a/src` instead of `/m`, that will no longer be a problem since `/m/a/prj/eclipse` is not inside `/m/a/src`.

Comment: @HighCommander4 Yes, I know. But why would't I be able to add a few files from `/m`?? They are there, and can't be moved.

Comment: It looks like you can add single files via `File -> New -> Other...`, choose `General -> File`, then under "Advanced", choose "Link to file in the file system".

Comment: Great, that works (Eclipse only issues a warning: `Location '/m/your_file.h' may overlap another resource. This can cause unexpected side-effects.`). Please add this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot link a directory that's an ancestor of the project's directory into the project because that would create a cycle in the project's directory structure.

Instead, you can link subdirectories of the ancestor directory (like `/m/a/src`, `/m/b/src`, etc. in your case) individually.

If you need a file that's contained directly in the ancestor directory, like `/m/file`, you can link an individual file:

- Go to `File -> New -> Other...`
- Choose `General -> File`
- Uder `Advanced`, choose "Link to file in the file system"